# Is $0^i$ defined number and what is it value where i :is unitary imaginary part?

Tags: complex-numbers

There are many examples of indeterminate cases, but I would like to know
if $0^i$ is a defined number or is it also one of the indeterminate cases? If it is defined, then what is its value? Is it equal to $0$?

Comment: The problem is: If $x, z$ are complex numbers, what is your definition of $x^z$? The most common definition is $e^{z\cdot \ln x}$, but in this case $x = 0$, and $\ln 0$ is very un-defined.

Comment: Exactly, just like $0$ is undefined because $\ln 0$ is undefined.

Comment: $0^5=e^{5\log 0}$ , is this true ?

Comment: No, this is true only when the exponent is complex, and the log is defined.

Comment: Although $i$ can be negated, it is never positive nor negative, so when zero is raised to its power, I can't say that it is undefined (e.g. raised to a negative power), nor can I say that it is defined as zero (e.g. raised to a positive power). In other words, I have no idea.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's indeterminate. Let $x=e^{-6\pi}=0.00000000651241$. Then $x^i=1$. Or, let $y=e^{-7\pi}=.000000000281427$. Then $y^i=-1$. There are other values of $z$ _really, really_ close to $0$ where $z^i=i$. The basic idea is that $z^i$ doesn't have a limit as $z$ goes to $0$, so I'm pretty sure $0^i$ is going to have to be indeterminate.

Comment: "indeterminate" and "undefined" are completely unrelated concepts!

Comment: @user21820 It makes most sense to leave it undefined because defining it would make $z^i$ discontinuous at zero.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: That is essentially what I said in my answer already, but involving differentiability rather than continuity.

Comment: Consider $$a^{ix}=e^{ix\ln a}=\cos (x\ln a)+i\sin(x\ln a)$$
Setting $x=1$ we have
$$a^{i} = \cos(\ln a)+i\sin(\ln a)$$
As $a\to 0$ Re ($a^{i}$) cycles $[-1,1]$, and vice versa for Im($a^{i}$).

Because it behaves like this and doesn't approach $\pm\infty$, I would say that it is indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of exponentiation via the concept of repeated multiplication gives naturally $0^5 = 0$, and more generally $0^n = 0$ for any positive integer $n$, but $0^0 = 1$. However, when we want to extend to complex exponentiation we have a slight problem. If we want $z^p$ for constant $p$ to be differentiable on its domain the best we can do is to exclude some path from $0$ to $\infty$. Commonly, we take for this path the negative real line including $0$. This would then be $e^{p\ln_\pi(z)}$ where $\ln_\pi$ is the logarithm with branch cut along the ray at angle $\pi$ from the origin. The domain cannot include $0$ because it cannot ever be made differentiable there. On the other hand, if we have a real exponent, we may want to define $0^p = 0$ so that it matches with alternative definitions for real exponentiation, and if $p$ is an integer it would also match the integer exponentiation definition of repeated multiplication.

So to directly answer your question, $0^i$ cannot be defined to have any meaningful value because of the singularity at the origin for any reasonable definition of $z^i$, which must agree with $e^{i\ln(z)}$ for some particular value of $\ln(z)$, for any nonzero $z$.

Comment: I don't know why you are wondred that 0^0 =1 ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: It is the only natural and meaningful possible definition. You cannot find any other. Please learn properly the difference between **undefined** and **indeterminate form**. The question of the **value** of $0^0$ has been adequately answered by some answers on this site, and has nothing to do with whether a limit has a form that **looks approximately like** $0^0$ or not.

Answer (score 1):

Claim: $0^i$ is **undefined**.

Reason:   The **Definition** of $a^b$ for complex numbers is:
$$
a^b = \exp\big(b\log a\big)
$$
and $\log 0$ is undefined.

**Reference:** L. Ahfors, *Complex Analysis*, 2nd edition.
$\log 0$ undefined, page 46.
Definition of $a^b$, page 47.

Comment: **added remark**  
Anyone who tells you $0^0=1$ for complex numbers is out of touch.  I will accept $a^0=1$ for integer $0$, of course.  But not for complex $0$.  In fact, not even for real $0$.

Comment: For complex exponent I agree with you that $0^0 = 1$ is not a good thing to have (not that it is impossible but just that it does not make anything better) for the reason in my answer. However, I'm not sure why you are adamant about the case for real exponent. What is your reasoning? There is a fairly elegant way to build the number systems via the path $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}_{\ge 0}+ \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and then one easily constructs the exponent $a^b$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ by defining it as $\sup \{ a^r : r \in \mathbb{Q}_{\ge 0} \land r \le b \}$, in which case $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: By the way it's not that I think there is much to **gain** by having $0^0 = 1$ for real exponentiation, but I don't see anything **lost** either.

Comment: This implies $0^1$ is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $0^0$ is indeterminate.

For general complex $z$, it will be compelling to say that $0^z$ is $\eta$ for all $z \neq 0$  (where $\eta$ might depend on $z$; in your case, you ask whether $\eta(z=0) = 0$) if
$$
\lim_{x,y\to 0} (x+iy)^z = 0
$$ 
because in that case, defining  $0^z$ in that way makes the function $f(v)=v^z$ continuous, and in any other way it is discontinuous at $0$.  So we have to see
if that limit is true.

In particular, for $z = i$, if we write $(x+iy) = e^r e^{i\theta}$ where $r = \log \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\cos \theta = x/r, \sin \theta = y/r$, then 
$$
(x+iy)^i = e^{-\theta} e^{ir}
$$
Now for any path approaching $(x,y) = (0,0)$, $e^{ir} \to e^0 = 1$.  But in particular for a straight line path in the complex plane approaching $0$, $\theta$ is constant, and $e^{-\theta}$ will be some non-zero value. So that statement about the value of $v^i$ approaching zero (or any other fixed value $\eta$) as $i$ approaches zero does not hold.

Therefore, $0^i$ is indeterminate.

Comment: "indeterminate" and "undefined" are completely unrelated concepts! The asker appears to be asking about the **value** of $0^i$, not whether it is an **indeterminate form for a limit**.